# ExtJS - dependent combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm trying to make a combobox that dependent from other combobox with default values but into the listeners of combobox must loading data of itself . I have the problem when using `this.store.loadData(todoItems)` with `todoItems` as an array of four positions.

This's store:

```
var cmb_items = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields : ['itemId', 'item'],
        data   : itemsMenu
});
```

I dont know why. Here is my code, can anyone lend me a hand?

```
{    
    xtype          : 'combo',
    store          : cmb_items,
    hiddenName     : 'id_item',
    valueField     : 'id_item',
    mode           : 'local',
    allowBlank     : false,
    value          : nombreItem,
    fieldLabel     : 'items',
    disabled       : true,
    name           : 'items',
    triggerAction  : 'all',
    emptyText      : 'Seleccione un item',
    editable       : false,
    id             : "items",
    anchor         : '90%',
    displayField   : 'item',
    listeners      : {
                select: function () {
                    idSistema = Ext.getCmp("sistemas").getValue();  
                    selectedMenu = Ext.getCmp("menus").getValue();
                    todoItems = getItemsMenu(selectedMenu,idSistema);
                    //alert(todoItems)
                    this.store.loadData(todoItems);
                    idItem     = this.getValue();

                        alert(idItem);          // RETURN UNDEFINED

                    for(i=0;i<this.store.getCount();i++){
                         if(todoItems[i][0]==idItem){
                             nombreItem = todoItems[i][1];
                             outItem    = todoItems[i][2];
                         }
                     }
            }                                    
             }
},
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not much clear with code, but if you're looking for combo depends another means, try my example.

```
    var countryStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['alpha2code','name'],
        data: [["BE","Belgium"],["BR","Brazil"],["BG","Bulgaria"]]
    });   

    function getState(stCode){
        var data=[];  
        switch(stCode){
            case 'BE':
                data=[["BE","Belgium1"],["BR","Brazil1"],["BG","Bulgaria1"]];
                break;

            case 'BR':
                data=[["BE","Belgium2"],["BR","Brazil2"],["BG","Bulgaria2"]];
                break;

            case 'BG':
                data=[["BE","Belgium3"],["BR","Brazil3"],["BG","Bulgaria3"]];
                break;
        }
        return data;  
    };

    var statesStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore( {
        fields: ['statecode','name']  
    });

    var stateForm = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel : 'Country',
        id : 'countryCombo',
        name : 'country',
        msgTarget : 'side',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        lazyRender : true,
        store : countryStore,
        mode: 'local',
        valueField : 'alpha2code',
        emptyText : 'Create or Select an partment',
        displayField : 'name',
        editable : true,
        listeners:{
            'select': function(combo,value,index){ 
                debugger;
                var input = combo.getValue();           
                var stateCombo=Ext.getCmp('statesCombo');
                //stateCombo.clearValue();
                //stateCombo.store.baseParams.countryID=input;
                stateCombo.store.loadData(getState(input));
            }
        }
    });

    var stateForm1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel : 'States',
        id : 'statesCombo',
        name : 'states',
        mode: 'local',
        msgTarget : 'side',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        lazyRender : true,
        store : statesStore,
        valueField : 'statecode',
        emptyText : 'Create or Select an Department',
        displayField : 'name',
        editable : true
    });

    var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title: 'World',
        labelWidth: 120,
        width: 350,
        padding: 10,
        items:[stateForm,stateForm1]
    });

    formPanel.render(document.body);
```

Comment: thanks men!
I could solve the problem, this forum would not let me post the answer to be new user.
itemID (fields) must have the same name as hiddenName-valueFields.
I has, hiddenName-valueFields = id_item

Sorry, my english is bad.
repeat, thanks!